# Writing Escape Characters in Plain Text with XML

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I'm having an issue parsing some XML with C#. To give an example, I'm taking some XML that contains the following tag:

```
<Message>Hello, my name is&#xA;Mr. Rogers</Message>
```

And parsing it with the following C# code:

```
var xmlData = XDocument.Load(filePath);
```

The problem that I'm having is that the above XML is being parsed as:

```
<Message>Hello, my name is
Mr. Rogers</Message>
```

when it needs to be parsed as:

```
<Message>Hello, my name is&#xA;Mr. Rogers</Message>
```

Is it possible to just have it parsed as the latter example in C#?

Comment: You can html encode the value.

Comment: "it needs to be parsed as [...]" - not according to the XML specification. Can you provide more context? What are you trying to accomplish, and what problem does the described parsing behavior result in?

Comment: The job of a parser is to deal with syntactic markers in the input, and `&#xa;` is one of those markers. If the parser didn't interpret it with its meaning (a representation of a newline) then it wouldn't be parsing the input, it would only be reading it.

Comment: I've looked at the source code of `XmlTextReader` (the thing underneath `XDocument.Load`). My conclusion is that it's impossible to do by playing with available settings. You can do some preprocessing of a raw text, replacing `&#xA;` with some magic string, and then postprocessing after `XDocument` loading to replace strings back.

Comment: `&#xA` is an [numeric character reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#dt-charref).  There's no way to prevent `XmlReader` from normalizing them.  The old `XmlTextReader` has a setting [`XmlTextReader.EntityHandling`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmltextreader.entityhandling) which has two values: `ExpandEntities` -- expand everhything; `ExpandCharEntities` -- expand character entities (including numeric character references) but return general entities as a reference.  There's no `ExpandNothing`.

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to do pre- and post-processing.

```cs
public XDocument LoadXDocument(string xmlString)
{
    const string replacer = "|||==|||";
    const string replacement = "&#xA;";
    xmlString = xmlString.Replace(replacement, replacer);

    XDocument doc;
    using (var reader = new StringReader(xmlString))
    {
        doc = XDocument.Load(reader);
    }

    foreach (var element in doc.Elements())
    {
        if (element.Value.Contains(replacer))
        {
            element.SetValue(element.Value.Replace(replacer, replacement));
        }
    }

    return doc;
}
```